# Function to get certain amount of lines from a file?

Tags: php

Was just wondering if there is anything that exists to retrieve a certain amount of lines from a file or should I just go ahead & make an array of it with `file` & then loop through it until I get the required data?

All I'm trying to do is get the first 11 lines of data from a file (or less if there aren't 11).

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, why don't you provide more detail so you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a small amount of lines, I'd recommend `fopen()`. This way for big files you haven't read in the whole thing.

Example:

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'r');
$i = 0;
while ( ($line = fgets($fp)) !== false && $i < 12 ) {
  ++$i;
  echo "$i: $line<br>";
}
fclose($fp);
```

Read more about [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Comment: +1 this is definitely the way to go. Shouldn't the loop however use `&&`, not `||` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "test.txt"; 
$lines = count(file($file)); 
echo "There are $lines lines in $file";
```

Comment: The OP is trying to "get a certain amount of lines" from the file, not get the number of lines. (Eg. Only lines 1 to 10)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to get the line in the cycle.